# What is the difference between metastable states and excited states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, definition, quantum-states

In the book *Mathematical concepts of quantum mechanics* ,Stephen J. Gustafson Israel,Michael Sigal, they say

> The notion of a resonance is a key notion in quantum physics. It
>   refers to a metastable state – i.e., to a state which behaves like a
>   stationary (bound) state for a long time interval, but which
>   eventually breaks up. In other words, the resonances are states of the
>   essential spectrum (i.e. scattering states), which for a long time
>   behave as if they were bound states. In fact, the notion of a bound
>   state is an idealization: most of the states which are (taken to be)
>   bound states in certain models, turn out to be resonance states in a
>   more realistic description of the system

What is  the difference between metastable states and  excited states?

Answer (score 2):

This is also a question I have. I have a partial answer which I'll present but I'm curious to hear from others if it is correct.

Forget the story about "resonances" for a moment and lets just think about decay of states.

In an atom we imagine a ground state and a number of excited states. At first we consider the states of an atom to be the quantum bound states of a classical coulomb potential. In this case if you prepare an atom in any of the states (ground or excited) it will live in that state forever.

However, in reality, there is decay from all of the excited states towards the ground state. The ground state of course doesn't decay. The reason for this decay is coupling to the electromagnetic field for atoms and additionally coupling to rotational and vibrational modes for molecules.

How fast the decay is out of any particular excited state depends on the particular details (such as geometry or symmetry) of the excited state and the states to which it decays. For any excited state we can specify a lifetime which quantifies how quickly that excited state is depopulated.

Now to answer the question.

My understanding is quite simply that metastable states are just like excited states but they have quantitatively very long lifetimes. Long compared to what? That depends on the context and the other states under consideration. For example, some state might have a long lifetime compared to other states at similar energies because the particular state is highly protected by certain symmetry selection rules so that it can only decay via high order effects.