# Clarification in the difference between metastable states and excited states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, terminology, definition, quantum-states

The answer of this question [What is the difference between metastable states and excited states?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524841/what-is-the-difference-between-metastable-states-and-exited-states)
 is that the difference lie in the the time that the systems lie in a given state.

So for example take the hydrogen atom and the state $2s$. 
Which time tell us the difference between the excited state and the metastable state?

Answer (score 1):

Long lifetime of an excited state is just an indication of  metastable state. The physical mechanism making a long lifetime is the presence of some dynamical obstruction of the direct mechanism for decaying to a lower state.

It is quite a widespread mechanism encompassing nuclear physics, electronic states in atoms and molecules and condensed phases of matter. An example coming from  atomic physics is the case of transitions forbidden by electric dipole selection rules. The much smaller matrix elements corresponding to quadrupole transitions makes the lifetime of those states significantly larger than in the case of electric dipole transitions.

In classical physics, metastable states require an activation energy to overcome an energy barrier separating the basin of the escited state from the ground state.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a metastable state is an excited state that lives longer.